# OpenSearch docker instance only allowing HTTPS connections

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I'm trying to get OpenSearch configured on my local machine, and am deploying it through docker-compose using the following configuration:

```
opensearch:
    image: opensearchproject/opensearch:1.0.0
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    environment:
      discovery.type: single-node
```

The instance starts successfully, however when trying to access it through the web interface, it only accepts HTTPS connections with the default basic auth credentials (admin:admin). i.e.

https://localhost:9200 asks me to enter administrator credentials, and upon doing so, returns an expected response:

```
{
  "name" : "a39dcf825899",
  "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "d2ZBZDQRTyG6SvYlCmX3Iw",
  "version" : {
    "distribution" : "opensearch",
    "number" : "1.0.0",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "34550c5b17124ddc59458ef774f6b43a086522e3",
    "build_date" : "2021-07-02T23:22:21.383695Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.8.2",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "The OpenSearch Project: https://opensearch.org/"
}
```

However when attempting to connect to the instance over HTTP, I get an empty response:

On chrome:

[image: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE]

Using the OpenSearch Python client on a Django instance running in a separate Docker container (part of the same docker-compose.yml):

`opensearchpy.exceptions.ConnectionError: ConnectionError(('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))) caused by: ProtocolError(('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response')))`

For reference, the code I am using to connect the OpenSearch Python client to the OpenSearch instance is:

```
cls._os_client = OpenSearch(
                [{"host": 'opensearch', "port": '9200'}],
                use_ssl=False,
                verify_certs=False,
                ssl_assert_hostname=False,
                ssl_show_warn=False
            )
```

How can I configure OpenSearch to allow insecure HTTP connections?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [disable security](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/security-plugin/configuration/disable), just add `DISABLE_SECURITY_PLUGIN=true` to your env.

Comment: Just asking, is there a way to have security enabled and still accept incoming HTTP requests?

Comment: Yes, you can fine-tune security via the yaml file or `-D` parameters, but it's generally not recommended, since the password can be easily intercepted in this case.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer @ilvar
Can you point in the direction where I can figure out how to do this fine-tuning?
Somehow I didn't stumble upon it yet and I'm desperate for a solution. ^^